# Получение данных в БД из html-страницы стороннего сайта

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Есть сайт, на котором требуется регулярно обновлять табличные данные (html-таблицы).

Есть некоторый функционал для того, чтобы новые таблицы можно было вручную в БД загружать.

И есть я, решительно не владеющая пхп (только хтмл,css, основы js).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли отредактировать прилагаемый код (я так понимаю, что именно он отвечает за загрузку данных в БД) таким образом, чтобы данные получать не из локального html-файла, а из html-кода определенного url-а стороннего сайта?

Насколько я понимаю, за это отвечает строка:

```
$html->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n".file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

При этом требуется получить не весь хтмл-файл с другого сайта, а только табличную его часть - определенный div c id=''

Что-то вроде такого может сработать? См. скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!
Вот код целиком:

```
    <?php

$user_name = 'Логин'; //Логин
$user_pass = 'Пароль'; //Пароль
$user = trim($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
$pass = trim($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
if(!($user_name==$user && $user_pass==$pass)){
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Manage"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Not authorized");
}
require_once __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'function.php';
$db = db();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST' && $_FILES['file']['error']===0){
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $html->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n".file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
    $total_rows = 0;
    $added = 0;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO property VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
    if($tr->getAttribute('class')=='restop'){
        continue;
    }
    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    if($tds->item(0)->hasAttribute('colspan')){
        continue;
    }
    $address = explode(',',$tds->item(2)->nodeValue);
        if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->bindValue(1,clearString($address[0]),SQLITE3_TEXT);//area
            $stmt->bindValue(2,clearString(implode(', ',array_slice($address,1))),SQLITE3_TEXT);//address
            $stmt->bindValue(3,clearString($tds->item(3)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//metro
            $stmt->bindValue(4,clearString($tds->item(4)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//floor
            $stmt->bindValue(5,intval($tds->item(1)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_INTEGER);//rooms
            $stmt->bindValue(6,clearString($tds->item(1)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//rooms_s
            $stmt->bindValue(7,clearString($tds->item(5)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_INTEGER);//sq_total
            $stmt->bindValue(8,clearString($tds->item(6)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//sq_room
            $stmt->bindValue(9,clearString($tds->item(7)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_INTEGER);//sq_kitchen
            $stmt->bindValue(10,clearString($tds->item(8)->nodeValue)=='+');//phone
            $stmt->bindValue(11,clearString($tds->item(9)->nodeValue)=='+');//furniture
            $stmt->bindValue(12,clearString($tds->item(10)->nodeValue)=='+');//fridge
            $stmt->bindValue(13,clearString($tds->item(11)->nodeValue)=='+');//st_metro
            $stmt->bindValue(14,intval($tds->item(12)->nodeValue));//price
            $stmt->bindValue(15,clearString($tds->item(13)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//term
            $stmt->bindValue(16,clearString(preg_replace(['/^[^,]+,/','/Взято.*$/'],'',$tds->item(16)->nodeValue)),SQLITE3_TEXT);//other
            $stmt->bindValue(17,date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));//created_at
            $stmt->execute();
            $added++;
        }
        $total_rows++;
    }
    $db->query('UPDATE config SET `value`="'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'" WHERE `name`="db_updated"');
    $db->query("DELETE FROM `property` WHERE strftime('%s',created_at)<(strftime('%s','now')-(3600*24*10))");
    ?>
    <h3>Добавлено <?=$added?> из <?=($total_rows)?> объектов!</h3>
    <?php
}
?>

<div style="width:50%;margin:10% auto;text-align:center;">
<div style='padding:40px;'>
    <div>Формат файла: <strong>html</strong></div>
    <div>Кодировка: <strong>UTF-8</strong></div>
</div>
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='file' accept='.txt,.html'>
    <button>Сохранить</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: конечно можно, как тут скачиваете страницу и распарсиваете ее регулярками или DOMDocument и выбираете данные.

Comment: Беда в том, что я пхп не владею (только html/css/основы js). Буду очень благодарна за  ссылку на мануал, как это сделать

Comment: Беда в том, что Stack Overflow - это не сервис для бесплатного написания кода. А мануала вам будет недостаточно, для этого нужны некоторые знания.

Comment: И простое (на первый взгляд) изменение источника получения данных не так просто, как кажется?  Я думала, что можно просто отредактировать ту строку, которая приведена первой. Нет? Что-то вроде такого решения: вместо file_get_contents - код, как на скрине (сейчас приложу к вопросу)

Comment: У вас вполне рабочий код, поэтому непонятна цель и суть вопроса. Направление мыслей верное, делайте так, как говорили и все получится. С другой стороны,вы тут же получите целый ворох новых проблем, я например не знаю таких сайтов, которые одномоментно разрешали бы парсить себя через file_get_contents и имели бы хоть какую-то ценность... Подавляющее большинство сайтов будут отдавать вам страницу ошибки уже после 10 попыток скачивания)))

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей. Сайт, откуда я буду брать данные - специализированный. Там доступ только для зарегистрированных юзеров. С этим еще тоже будут проблемы. Но это уже следующий этап.   А про цель вопроса... Я первый раз пытаюсь править php, поэтому не уверена, верно ли мыслю. Еще раз благодарю

Comment: Сергей, если Вы оформите свой комментарий в виде ответа, я смогу выбрать его лучшим.